# How to make buttons not dissapear while defining clear.canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

So esentially for this presentation I have to make a game and on the next to last GUI I have 4 buttons, once clicking one of them its supposed delete EVERYTHING but when doing

```
def clear_command():
    canvas.delete("all")
```

It shows only the "Mulitplikasjon" button and not the other ones. Im inexperienced in coding and thought it would work to just... make more definitions but that doesn't really work.

### I tried making more definitions hoping it would solve the issue but it didn't

```
from tkinter import *

# Functions
def launch_button():

    canvas.delete("all")

#def enter_user_names() :
    global start_img, screen
    global player_1, player_2

    canvas.delete('all')
    player_1 = StringVar()
    player_2 = StringVar()

    player_label_1 = Label(screen, text='Skriv inn navnet til spiller1:', font=("ariel", 16))

    canvas.create_window(250, 300 - 100, window=player_label_1)

    player_label_2 = Label(screen, text='Skriv inn navnet til spiller 2:', font=("ariel", 16))

    canvas.create_window(250, 400 - 100, window=player_label_2)

    player_entry_1 = Entry(screen, font=("ariel", 14, "italic"), width=50, textvariable=player_1)

    canvas.create_window(280, 300 - 50, window=player_entry_1)

    player_entry_2 = Entry(screen, font=("ariel", 14, "italic"), width=50, textvariable=player_2)
    canvas.create_window(280, 400 - 50, window=player_entry_2)

    custom_button = Button(screen, text="Forsett", bg='red', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command=math_operators)
    canvas.create_window(260, 400, window=custom_button)

def math_operators():

    canvas.delete('all')

    addisjon_button = Button(screen, text="Addisjon", bg='red', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command=math_operators)
    canvas.create_window(150, 200, window=addisjon_button)

    divisjon_button = Button(screen, text="Divisjon", bg='green', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command=math_operators)
    canvas.create_window(360, 200, window=divisjon_button)

    substraksjon_button = Button(screen, text="Substraksjon", bg='blue', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command=math_operators)
    canvas.create_window(380, 300, window=substraksjon_button)

    multiplikasjon_button = Button(screen, text="Multiplikasjon", bg='orange', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command=math_operators)
    canvas.create_window(150, 300, window=multiplikasjon_button)

def select_math_operators():
    canvas.delete("all")

def clear_command():
    canvas.delete("all")

def start_game():
    global screen, canvas
    screen = Tk()
    title = screen.title('Math Duel')
    canvas = Canvas(screen, width=500, height=500)
    canvas.pack()

    # image logo
    logo_img = PhotoImage(file='methbettle.png')
    # resize
    logo_img = logo_img.subsample(2, 2)
    canvas.create_image(250, 150, image=logo_img)

    # Select Path for saving the file
    path_label = Label(screen, text="Launch game?", font=('Arial', 15))
    select_btn = Button(screen, text="Launch", bg='red', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15),
                        command=launch_button)
    # Add to window
    canvas.create_window(250, 280, window=path_label)
    #    canvas.create_window(250, 330, window=start_game)
    canvas.create_window(250, 330, window=select_btn)

    screen.mainloop()

start_game()
```

Comment: make them children of canvas instead of screen

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, when pressing one of the buttons, it goes to the same function where the buttons are defined, so they are constantly being generated.

I give you two ways to do that, it is really the same function written in different ways, but depending on what you need, you may find one or the other useful.

**1:**

```
def math_operators():

    canvas.delete('all')

    addisjon_button = Button(screen, text="Addisjon", bg='red', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command = lambda: canvas.delete('all'))
    canvas.create_window(150, 200, window=addisjon_button)
```

Just put the command `lambda: canvas.delete('all')` on each of the buttons you want to do that.

**2:**

```
def clear_fun():
    canvas.delete('all')

def math_operators():

    canvas.delete('all')

    addisjon_button = Button(screen, text="Addisjon", bg='red', padx='22', pady='5', font=('Arial', 15), command=clear_fun)
    canvas.create_window(150, 200, window=addisjon_button)
```

Here I only linked with the `clear_fun` function but I understand that you have already tried this and it didn't work for you. In my case, this is the result.

[image]